# Concatenate videos from a socket and create a live stream

Tags: ffmpeg

I know the title is not clear so I'll explain as best I can.When I mean concatenating from a socket is this way
This is the command I use:

```
ffmpeg -i tcp://localhost:8080 -f flv rtmp://localhost/oflaDemo/stream1497985143577
```

Which makes the server simply send a 3gp file that is converted to flv and sent to the server stream, everything looks good the first file on the client, but when the server starts reading the second file and sends it, it no longer shows anything in the video. And ffmpeg throws this error.

```
[flv @ 000000000060bc80] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 3077
3, current: 16928; changing to 30773. This may result in incorrect timestamps in
 the output file.
[flv @ 000000000060bc80] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 3077
3, current: 16954; changing to 30773. This may result in incorrect timestamps in
 the output file.
[flv @ 000000000060bc80] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 3077
3, current: 16981; changing to 30773. This may result in incorrect timestamps in
 the output file.
[flv @ 000000000060bc80] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 3077
3, current: 17007; changing to 30773. This may result in incorrect timestamps in
```

Investigate a bit about this error and some suggestions say it is for the version of ffmpeg but I already have the recent version, I tried everything but only the first file that is sent to live server, but the second I no longer appreciate some suggestion.

Comment: It's the expected behavior. When you start sending the second file you're creating a discontinuity as the timestamps and/or encoding parameters change. If you want to play multiple files one after another use the concat demuxer without sockets.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but the problem here is that the videos are dynamically loaded are not static so I thought loading them from the socket would be easy as the server decides which load, exisitra a way or definitely can not?

Comment: What I did was write my own concat demuxer based on the default one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, using a demuxer only works if the files are static, in this case I need to be always dynamic of the same format, which makes the server where ffmpeg is connected is that loads file dynamically and sends it for transmission, but Demuxer can not do that, right?

Comment: You could implement a sort of protocol and when `ffmpeg` needs the next file it makes a request to the server and retrieves the next file location. This way you can fetch it using HTTP, make use of caching and/or CDNs.